# How to initialize/declare a large array that occupies more memory than Master process has access to when parallelizing a code using MPI

Tags: arrays, parallel-processing, fortran, mpi, distributed-computing

I am trying to parallelize a math fortran code that iteratively solves a set of partial differential equations on a 3D lattice. What I would like to do is declare a big array and distribute it among different processors for iterative computation. What I am really confused about is how to initialize this array if it occupies more memory than one process has access to. For example, if my big array occupies 5 GB of memory and the master processor has only access to 2 GB of memory, how do I even initialize/declare it without crashing ? Is there a way to declare one large "distributed" array.

Also, if this is not possible, how should I divide my big array into multiple arrays of smaller size on multiple processors. Operationally, what I am asking is that if I declare my big array "f" as follows,

```
        integer ierr, taskid, numtasks
        real*8 f
        dimension f(-nx:nx,-ny:ny,-nz:nz)
        call MPI_INIT( ierr )
        call MPI_COMM_RANK( MPI_COMM_WORLD, taskid, ierr )
        call MPI_COMM_SIZE( MPI_COMM_WORLD, numtasks, ierr )

    if(taskid==0) then
         DO 10, i = -nx, nx
             DO 20, j = -ny, ny
                Do 30, k = -nz, nz 

                f(i,j,k) = 0.0

    30       CONTINUE
    20    CONTINUE
    10 CONTINUE

    else

c Do something else !

    call MPI_Finalize(ierr)
```

where nx, ny, and nz are big, the Master processor will run out of memory and crash. So, what is the best way to handle a situation like this. I have searched on google a lot and I couldn't find an example that explains what to do in a situation like this. I am a beginner, so please excuse me for anything that I am not getting here.

Comment: This is a principal problem in most of high-performance computing. Often, the specifics of your system to be solved needs to be considered. For example, in my field the PDE's are hyperbolic so the domain is decomposed into distinct partitions for each processor.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I understand that we need to decompose our domain. But I am not sure how to initialize such a set of distributed arrays. How do I make sure that a specific processor accesses only the data I want to assign (What should be the syntax ?). Thanks.

Comment: Nesting subscripts backwards is problematical. On 64 bit os you shouldn't have a problem if the array is allocatable.

Comment: There is no specific syntax. Each process just declares arrays (for example from `1` to `local_nx`, or something similar. Are you sure you understand the distributed processes well? They are completely separate, they do not know about each other internals, they just exchange some messages. And, please, if you are learning, learn `END DO` ond other modern Fortran features. Do not program like in the 1970s.

Comment: There are many resources with examples. A very quick web search reveals http://wgropp.cs.illinois.edu/courses/cs598-s16/lectures/lecture25.pdf but there are many many more. Also http://www.netlib.org/utk/papers/mpi-book/node44.html

Comment: As I mentioned, I am a beginner. What I mean by syntax is how do I make sure that a process of a given rank only accesses the array I want to assign it. Let's say I divide my big array f into two smaller arrays f1 and f2. Now, how do I make sure that f1 is only initialized for rank 0 process and f2 is only initialized for rank 1 process. What code I should write for this ? I couldn't find examples on google for this.

Comment: Your question is very strange. Each process has a local array. It can't access anything else. Simply can't (*ok, it can, but it is too advanced*). It just passes and receives messages.

Comment: Does that mean global arrays cannot be defined for parallel computing ? I wanted to have a big global array f, which I divide into smaller ones for specific processors. This global array should be defined over whatever the number of processes we have but specific processes should only have access to their portion of the global array. I guess my assumption is wrong.

Comment: See the answer, it is one big array *conceptually*, but it is not a single variable.

Comment: BTW you may look at coarrays in Fortran 2008 to see something like global arrays with an easy access.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to clarify how distributed array work. There is a big global array. But it does not exist anywhere! It is just a concept. Each process has a small piece of this array.

There are various ways to decompose an array, but consider a simple 1D decomposition of a 1D array.

In a serial program it would be one array:

```
real A(1:global_n)
```

with coordinates

```
real x(1:global_n)
```

these coordinates are, for example,

```
x = [( x0 + hx * i, i = 1, global_n )]
```

But in a parallel program each process has a small array. One possibility is:

```
real A(1:local_n)
```

with coordinates

```
real x(1:local_n)
```

each process starts at `local_x0`

```
x = [( local_x0 + hx * i, i = 1, local_n )]
```

Then you can initialize the array simply using the coordinates like

```
do i = 1, local_n
  A(i) = function_of_x(x(i))
end do
```

For example, if you have an array from 1..30 with coordinates from 0.1 to 3, and 3 processes, then you would have

```
local_n = 10
```

in each process.

Then you would have for process 0

```
local_x0 = 0.1
```

for process 1

```
local_x0 = 1.1
```

and for process 2

```
local_x0 = 2.1
```